# How to set customer id for a quote in Magento?

Tags: cart, magento-1, quote, sales-quote

I added a product into the cart and tried to map customer id, email to that quote using the code below

```
$product_id = 123; 
$qty        = 1; 
$product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$cart       = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart'); 
$cart->init();

$superAttributeArray = array('151' => '3');
$params = array(
    'product' => $product_id,
    'qty'     => $qty,
    'super_attribute' => $superAttributeArray
);
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();

$currenQuoteId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId();
$store = Mage::getSingleton('core/store')->load(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStore($store)->load($currenQuoteId);
$quote
    ->setCustomerId('1')
    ->setCustomerEmail('test@gmail.com')
    ->setCustomerFirstname('firstname')
    ->setCustomerLastname('lastname');
$quote->save();
```

When I try to set customerid,email,fname,lname am getting the error

> "Mage registry key "controller" already exists".

Can anyone help me in fixing this issue?

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace for that error from exceptions.log? Something is calling `Mage::register('controller', ...)`, but it's not clear what from your code.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737069/mage-registry-key-controller-already-exists

Comment: Is there a reason for manually loading the quote and not using `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();`?

Answer (score 0):

Due to setStore it will throw error.remove setstore.
load your quote using below code

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer())
```