# Programatically transefer cart items to another user

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to transfer  cart items from one user to another programatically.
Like all items of user 'A' should be transferred to cart of user 'B'. I tried to update customer_id in sales_flat_quote table but it din't solve the problem. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

take a look in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` class.
There are some functions like `assignCustomer` or `setCustomer` that may fit with your request.
Source : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79257/33619

Comment: Will it also flush the cookies ? as when I updated the database, cart gets empty when i flush the cookies. Do I need to explicitly handle the cookie or it will take care of it ?

Comment: This is only slightly different from the case, where a user has something in the cart and then logs in to her account. Take a look how that works (you need to flush the old session and. create a new session, with perhaps a bit of old and mostly new data).